# Are there any foods / nutrients that parents should definitely take into account in feeding infants and children?

Tags: veganism, nutrition, diet, children

Everyone knows about vitamin B12. There's loads of other things to think about, omega 3, other lipids, proteins, plus glycaemic index of carbs.

**What's the best way to approach a complete diet the vegan way for infants and children?**

There are too many horror stories to get it wrong.

Comment: Do you think that your question is covered by [this one](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/182/70)? It isn't an exact duplicate, but it is a bit broader and so it includes some information about what nutrients to consider.

Comment: @Erica♦ Pretty much covered, need to spend some time with pen and paper to get it all straight. Thanks.